# Subscriber not getting the message in Redis

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis

I am using docker and redis to learn how multi container in docker work.I am using below simple flask application which has a publish and subscribe code.However I don't see any message received  by the subscriber

```
import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

client = redis.Redis(host="redis-server", decode_responses=True)


def event_handler(msg):
    print("Handler", msg, flush=True)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("Request received",flush=True)
    print(client.ping(), flush=True)
    client.publish("insert", "This is a test 1")
    client.publish("insert", "This is a test 2")
    client.publish("insert", "This is a test 3")
    ps = client.pubsub()
    ps.subscribe("insert",)
    print(ps.get_message(), flush=True)
    print(ps.get_message(), flush=True)
    print(ps.get_message(), flush=True)
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

and below is my docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis-server:
    image: "redis"
  python-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4001:5000"
```

and docker file

```
# Specify the base image

FROM python:alpine

# specify the working directory

WORKDIR /usr/app

# copy the requiremnts file

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["python","./app.py"]
```

And below is the output I am getting

[image]

Can someone please help me in identifying what I am doing wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix above issue by creating two separate scripts one for publisher and other for subscriber and starting the subscriber first.